# What's the name of the part of the URL before the query string?

Tags: http, url, naming-conventions

Take the following URL: http://3.chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p&chd=t:1,2,3&chl=a|b|c&chs=300x100

It can be broken down as follows:

- Protocol: `http`
- Hostname: `3.chart.apis.google.com`
- Path: `chart`
- Query: `cht=p&chd=t:1,2,3&chl=a|b|c&chs=300x100`

I'm looking for the name of the protocol, hostname and path? i.e. everything up to the query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no canonical name for those parts of the URL (or URI if you like) up to but not including the querystring. the entirety of that string is a URL which consists of:

Scheme/Protocol
   Domain
   Port (Assumed as default for protocol if not specified)
   Path
   Querystring

see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator

Comment: No canonical name, now I know. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

In terms of [URI as specified by RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), the URI `http://3.chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p&chd=t:1,2,3&chl=a|b|c&chs=300x100` consists of the following components:

- `http` – [scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1)
- `//3.chart.apis.google.com/chart` – hierarchical part

  - `3.chart.apis.google.com` – [authority](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2)

    - `3.chart.apis.google.com` – [host](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2)
  - `/chart` – [path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3)
- `cht=p&chd=t:1,2,3&chl=a|b|c&chs=300x100` – [query](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)